# PHP == not working for Float values

Tags: php, comparison

I am having a scenario where I get response from payment gateway in which I have total.
Like `1250.00`. Now I cross check this total with my cart value which I get from database.
Issue is some time

```
if($cartTotal == $paymentTotal)
```

fails most of the time it works but for certain times it fail. I am not sure whats the Issue.

I have tried `trim, type casting, === strcmp` but somehow it fails for certain transactions. I have type casted the values to int, float, string.

Can anybody point me in right direction ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: @deceze I'll try `bccomp` for it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the float variables like this:

```
if(abs($cartTotal-$paymentTotal) > 0.00001)
```

Answer (score -1):

Commas are an example of things that can mess up PHP's number handling

Try this function to cleanse your numbers:

```
/**
 * Clean up any numbers
 * Remove any characters apart from numbers and point (.)
 * Then explicitly cast to a float
 * @param $amount
 * @return float
 */
function numberSanitise($amount)
{
    $amount = floatval(preg_replace('%[^0-9.]%', '', $amount));
    return $amount;
}
```